# Symfony 5 and Sonata Admin Bundle Compatability?

Tags: composer-php, sonata-admin, symfony5

A quick question about using the Sonata Admin Bundle with Symfony 5.

Has anyone been able to run a simple Composer require on the project and do the actual installation without minimum stability errors?

Cheers

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any release of the bundle that supports Symfony 5.

Comment: The compatibility with Symfony 5 and Sonata is on going, https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/5788.